# MalwareBytes Anti-Exploit occasionally triggering on a CMD/Powershell get softwarelicensing something from 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f

Tags: powershell, malwarebytes

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe (([WMISEARCHER]'SELECT ID FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE ApplicationID=''55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f''').Get()).ID | % {echo ('ID
```

The above is as much of the command as the popup for anti-exploit shows me. I've confirmed it's a real popup and not one from my browser. It's happened a few times in the last week, though I didn't check the command very closely at the time (though I'll be on the watch for it now). I expect it's similar each time if not the same.

Something appears to be running in the background or triggered based on what I'm browsing maybe? I was browsing Reddit when this one came up.

The only enabled apps on startup are the anti-exploit app itself, iCue (for corsair keyboard), and SecurityHEalthSystray.exe (windows defender).

I have many other types of applications open, but stuff I usually would. I can methodically close each and see if it doesn't come up, but that would take forever and have a lot of impact on my computer user.Is there any way to debug or discover what could be causing this outside of methodical shutdown and waiting?

Comment: Which process is issuing it? If you don't know, install [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), and next time it happens drag its bullseye over the message.

Comment: This appears to be a query to ascertain Windows license; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1280797/capturing-windows-os-license-information and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/massgravel/Microsoft-Activation-Scripts/master/MAS/All-In-One-Version/MAS_AIO.cmd . If it's a corporate PC, check if IT has made a Scheduled Task or remotely-run task to check product license.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, it's not a corporate computer and has never been used as one.

Comment: @harrymc, I didn't know it could do something like that! I'll check it out! If it really works that way, can you leave this as an answer? Because the heart of this question is how to find out what's causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally thought to look in MalwareBytes Anti-exploit logs and I can see a series of these. Four attempts each, once a week at the same time, 12:00. They run similar commands looking for Windows or Office and "KMS Client" or whatever.

Realizing it might be a scheduled task, I checked the task scheduler and looked to see if anything last run at that time and found an Online_KMS_Activation_Script-Renewal - Weekly activation task. This is clearly the culprit and now I just need to figure out what it belongs to.

Bottom line, I should have checked the logs and then gone from there :)

Comment: KMS aka KMSpico is for if you don't wanna pay for windows or office

Comment: For KMS, this is not always true, if you are in an enterprise environment with both MAK and KMS keys with your licenses/subscriptions related to Windows, you can spin up a 100% legit KMS server to activate Office and Windows legally and 100% legit for Windows Activation. I'm not sure about the KMSpico, but KMS has legit and legal MS compliant purposes too for those that do pay MS. I try to do KMS over MAK key because it's easier to manage and activation is automation once you set it up in a domain environment. I'm not familiar with a Task Scheduler task that activates, it's usually automatic.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/kms-create-host and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/kms-activation-planning per "*KMS activations are valid for 180 days, a period known as the activation validity interval. KMS clients must renew their activation by connecting to the KMS host at least once every 180 days to stay activated. By default, KMS client computers attempt to renew their activation every seven days. After a client's activation is renewed, the activation validity interval begins again.*", so that task is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to find the owner process of any window or dialog
by using the free
[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Once the window is displayed, open Process Explorer and drag the
bullseye icon
[image]
and drop it over the window. The owning process will automatically
be selected in Process Explorer, so you can examine its properties
and those of its parent(s).

Double-click the entry of the selected process to examine its properties.

Comment: This is an amazing revelation to find after 30 years of computing, though I realized after the fact that what I'm looking for is what CAUSED the popup and if I use this tool, it will tell me Malwarebytes Anti-Exploit owns the popup instead of what triggered it, I did think to check the logs, but it doesn't tell me much more. Still struggling to find a source.

Comment: If this happens soon enough, you could monitor the execution of Windows using the utility [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). You may filter on "Operation is Process Create" to find the launching process.

Comment: Answered although I see that you've found the culprit.